# How to compare small and large scale model of an IC engine to predict force, torque, rpm etc generated by actual engine?

Tags: design, simulation, mechanical-failure, solidworks, cad

I have this [6 cylinder radial engine](http://www.inventorwizard.nl/gallery/air%20radial%20engine/Air%20Radial%20Engine.html) designed in Solidworks.
[image: Rendering]
Rendering
[image: Blueprint]
Blueprint (Source:Inventor Wizards)

And I want to perform some motion analysis on this engine to make some prediction about it's feasibility.
So by now I have successfully completed the motion study simulation and generated plots of piston acceleration against time.
[image: Acc-Time Plot]
Plotted for a crankshaft speed of 200RPM.

Can i use some method or this data to predict acceleration of large scale model of this engine?

Comment: Can't seem to follow the link.  I get a "Server not found" error.

Comment: @NickAlexeev I'm sorry, I posted the link in plain text. The question might be moderated. Anyways, I've corrected the link do check it now.

Comment: The link now points to a zip archive. Seriously, if you want people to take a look at your question, you're going to have to make it a lot easier for them than that. Put a key image or two right in the question, and be more specific about the issue you want us to address.

Comment: @DaveTweed Actually there was a whole lot of blueprints for individual parts, and I was posting with the app. I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. Now I've pointed the link to the main site (Instead of the blueprint files). And added some images. Kindly check it now.

Comment: OK, first question: Do you understand why commercial radial engines almost universally have an odd number of cylinders?

Comment: Yes, i think the primary reason is that a 4 stroke IC engine needs 2 revolution of the crankshaft to completes its 4 processes (suction,compression,ignition,exhaust). So an odd cylinder arrangement helps in firing half of the engines in one revolution and other half in second, so by this way we get power stroke for each revolution of crankshaft. If there were even cylinders all of them need to be fired in one single revolution (as the case is), which will apparently cause less smooth running engine with balancing and vibration issues i guess.

Comment: The link suggests this isn't an IC engine in the first place, so the even number of cylinders isn't a problem. However, that makes the purpose of the question even less clear.